# ONVIF: wsdl files from website vs from device

Tags: wsdl, onvif

I am trying to write an ONVIF client to manage an ONVIF compliant device. For a specific service, I can get the wsdl file from the device, or get it from onvif.org. What is the difference between these two methods?

Answer (score 1):

With the adoption of profiles, even if they are different nothing changes. ONVIF specifications for the services and their WSDL files may change, but the set of features and functions mandatory for a profile conformant device is immutable.

Therefore there is no change in practice.